# Firebase Storage vs Firebase Realtime Database for storing sensitive images

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm looking for a safe way to store users' sensitive media like picture of driver's license. As far as I know, there is no way to access Firebase Realtime Database from Firebase Storage Rules to see if an user is authorized to view the media. Correct me if I'm wrong. There are some ways in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security) to allow certain users to access the media, but it doesn't work out for me because there might be multiple users that will access the media and their permission status might be changed in the future.

On the other hand, there is Firebase Realtime Database. It will be secure. We can use database rules to control user access. However, there are some problems with using database like:

- Cost
- Latency
- Storage size

Is there a workaround to dynamically give permissions to multiple users for accessing Firebase Storage? Or, using Firebase Realtime Database is actually fine to store images? If neither is possible, is it safe to use Firebase Storage without any additional security?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, Realtime Database is not suitable for storing large binary objects like images.  It's far more effective to use Cloud Storage for that.

Cloud Storage for Firebase has [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start) similar to Realtime Database, except they are expressed in a different language.  You can protect images per-user along with Firebase Authentication.  I would start with that.

Comment: Let's say we have a group of users who will access the same image in Firebase Storage. We put each of their ids into the metadata. We can check if their user id is in the metadata before allowing them to view it. However, we might need to remove one of the users from the group later. Can we just update the metadata without duplicating the image? Another problem is the number of users who have the permission. What if thousands of users will need to access the same image. How many ids can we put into the metadata?

Comment: Yes, you can update the metadata whenever you want. I don't think you will run into any limits, as long as you pay for the storage.  You might want to read the documentation on Cloud Storage metadata to better understand how it works.